# Remove HTML tags in AppEngine Python Env (equivalent to Ruby's Sanitize)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, html-sanitizing

I am looking for a python module that will help me get rid of HTML tags but keep the text values. I tried BeautifulSoup before and I couldn't figure out how to do this simple task. I tried searching for Python modules that could do this but they all seem to be dependent on other libraries which does not work well on AppEngine.

Below is a sample code from Ruby's sanitize library and that's what I am after in Python:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sanitize'

html = '<b><a href="http://foo.com/">foo</a></b><img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg" />'

Sanitize.clean(html) # => 'foo'
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

-e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<b><a href="http://foo.com/">foo</a></b><img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg" />'
>>> bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)  
>>> bs.findAll(text=True)
[u'foo']
```

This gives you a list of (Unicode) strings.  If you want to turn it into a single string, use `''.join(thatlist)`.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That should work -- last time I tried BeautifulSoup I got into parsing node by node and that became very slow. Now that I have changed the way I am handling my HTML code, I could use BeautifulSoup for cleanup. I totally forgot about the text=True option. Thanks!

Comment: To use into App Engine, install BeatifulSoup locally and use the file in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages. Or just use this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9632169/BeautifulSoup.py

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use separate libs then you can import standard django utils. For example:

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
html = '<b><a href="http://foo.com/">foo</a></b><img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg'
stripped = strip_tags(html)
print stripped 
# you got: foo
```

Also its already included in Django templates, so you dont need anything else, just use filter, like this:

```
{{ unsafehtml|striptags }}
```

Btw, this is one of the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

Using lxml:

```
htmlstring = '<b><a href="http://foo.com/">foo</a></b><img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg" />'

from lxml.html import fromstring

mySearchTree = fromstring(htmlstring)

for item in mySearchTree.cssselect('a'):
    print item.text
```

Comment: Thanks, bigredbob. Took me a while to get lxml running on my machine to your code - it works! I have not tested it on App-Engine yet and will let you know if it does not work. lxml also seems to manage bad markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

def getText(el):
    ret = ''
    for child in el.childNodes:
        if child.nodeType == 3:
            ret += child.nodeValue
        else:
            ret += getText(child)
    return ret

html = '<b>this is <a href="http://foo.com/">a link </a> and some bold text  </b> followed by <img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg" /> an image'
dom = parseString('<root>' + html + '</root>')
print getText(dom.documentElement)
```

Prints:

> this is a link  and some bold text   followed by  an image

Comment: Thanks Amarghosh. I think minidom is supported on app-engine so that should work well.

Comment: Amarghosh, I have accepted Alex's answer as BeautifulSoup seems to handle bad markup better. Thanks very much for the snippet, however and I can certainly use it for the markup that I can trust.

Answer (score 1):

Late, but.

You can use Jinja2.Markup()

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Markup.striptags

```
from jinja2 import Markup 
Markup("<div>About</div>").striptags()
u'About'
```