# How to get the content of a Html page in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have downloaded the web page into an html file. I am wondering what's the simplest way to get the content of that page. By content, I mean I need the strings that a browser would display.

To be clear:

Input:

```
<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>
       <body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.
       <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.
       </html>
```

Output:

```
Page title This is paragraph one. This is paragraph two.
```

putting together:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

def removeHtmlTags(page):
    p = re.compile(r'''<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>''')
    return p.sub('', page)

def removeHtmlTags2(page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    return ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

#### Related

- [Python HTML removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598817/python-html-removal)
- [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)
- [What is a light python library that can eliminate HTML tags? (and only text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620363/what-is-a-light-python-library-that-can-eliminate-html-tags-and-only-text)
- [Remove HTML tags in AppEngine Python Env (equivalent to Ruby’s Sanitize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415008/remove-html-tags-in-appengine-python-env-equivalent-to-rubys-sanitize)
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (famous *don't use regex to parse html* rant)

Comment: which tags are you talking about? could you be more specific?

Comment: <html> <head> are tags. I don't want them I need a actual string that displays on a browser.

Comment: Why did the dots disappeared in the output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parse the HTML with [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup).

To get all the text, without the tags, try:

```
''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html
I don't see renderContents() function works here. I want to delete the tags.

Comment: @Yin Zhu - Ah, renderContents works on sub-parts, not the whole document. I replaced the technique with one snipped from the documentation.

Comment: @Yin Zhu: renderContents occurs 6 times in the referenced documentation.  Please use a web browser that supports page search.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I use lxml because it's a swiss-army knife...

```
from lxml import html

print html.parse('http://someurl.at.domain').xpath('//body')[0].text_content()
```

This tells lxml to retrieve the page, locate the `<body>` tag then extract and print all the text.

I do a lot of page parsing and a regex is the wrong solution most of the time, unless it's a one-time-only need. If the author of the page changes their HTML you run a good risk of your regex breaking. A parser is a lot more likely to continue working.

The big problem with a parser is learning how to access the sections of the document you are after, but there are a lot of XPATH tools you can use inside your browser that simplify the task.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at [**Extracting data from HTML  documents - Dive into Python**](http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/index.html#dialect.divein) because [**HERE**](http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/introducing_sgmllib.html) it does (almost)exactly what you want.

Comment: Links are broken

Answer (score 1):

The best modules for this task are lxml or html5lib; Beautifull Soap is imho not worth to use anymore. And for recursive models regular expressions are definitly the wrong method.

Comment: Would you like to explain why Beautiful Soup is no longer worth using?

Comment: Seconded. What changed about HTML that made Beautiful Soup irrelevant? It abstracts away a lot of the issues with imperfect HTML.

Answer (score -2):

If I am getting your question correctly, this can simply be done by using urlopen function of urllib. Just have a look at this function to open an url and read the response which will be the html code of that page.

Comment: you're not getting it right, OP says: *I have downloaded the web page into an html file.*

Answer (score -3):

The quickest way to get a usable sample of what a browser would display is to remove any tags from the html and print the rest. This can, for example, be done using python's `re`.

Comment: this cannot be done using regex. please, don't confuse people.

Comment: Please explain. I'm not talking about a perfect solution, just about a rough way to get the contents in acceptable quality (I'm aware that the approach is limited). Removing tags is just looking for `<..> and </..>`, so why exactly is it not possible using regexes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: "Now you have two problems" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html