# Python HTML parsing

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-parsing

I am currently trying to make a program that given a word will look up its definition and return it. Although I have gotten this to work, I had to resort to using RegEx to search for the text between the tags where the definitions are stored. What is a more efficient way to do this using python 3.x?

Comment: Try searching first. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+html+parse all of these questions are applicable to your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the content of a Html page in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416823/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-html-page-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/) works for Python 3. It has an ElementTree compatible API, but is using c libraries behind the scenes, so it's fast, and it supports Xpaths, which is a nice way of parsing (sometimes).

Answer (score 4):

Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) a good HTML parser for Python. (works with Python 3.x too, although unless you are deep into a Python 3.0 project, consider using 2.7)

Comment: yep, BeautifulSoup is the secret sauce!

Answer (score 2):

Your's a pretty simple requirement when it comes to HTML parsing. Python standard library includes [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module which should be helpful to do the task which you are planning to undertake. Look for the example snippet which is given in that page.

Also, **never make the mistake** of parsing HTML/XML using regex. You may not know when it will get insanely complicated and it is a bad idea under any situation too.